# Django: how to pass data from view to forms to validate it

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, view

In my form class I have a contact field in string to save several contacts separated by semicolons. In the request, contacts is an array so I do a ";".join(contacts) to get one contact field for my class form. I would like to pass this ";"join(contacts) contact from my view to the form class to validate it.

I simplified the code to focus on the part I have difficulties

the model class:

```
class Accounts(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=255))
```

the form class:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Accounts
import re

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField()
    
    class Meta:        
        model = Accounts
        fields = ('phone_numbers')

    def clean_phone_numbers(self):
        phone_numbers = self.cleaned_data['phone_numbers']
        if len(phone_numbers) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Your number must not be less than 10 digits')
        if len(phone_numbers) > 15:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Your number must not exceed 15 digits')
        regex = '^[0-9]{10,15}$'
        if not (re.fullmatch(regex, phone_numbers)):
            raise forms.ValidationError('The number must not contain letters')
        return phone_numbers
```

The view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .forms import RegisterForm
import logging

# Create your models here.

def register_user(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        numbers = request.POST.getlist('phone_numbers')
        numbers = ",".join(numbers)
        
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, phone_numbers=numbers) # Error
            
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', context)
```

the template:

```
<form action="#" method="post" novalidate>
    <div id="number-composant">
        <div class="form-group" id="input-field">
            <label for="{{form.phone_numbers.id_for_label}}">Votre numero *</label>
            <div>
                {% if form.is_bound %}
                    {% if form.phone_numbers.errors %}
                        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="{{form.phone_numbers.id_for_label}}" name="{{form.phone_numbers.html_name}}" value="{{form.phone_numbers.value}}" required>
                    {% else %}
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{form.phone_numbers.id_for_label}}" name="{{form.phone_numbers.html_name}}" value="{{form.phone_numbers.value}}" required>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{form.phone_numbers.id_for_label}}" name="{{form.phone_numbers.html_name}}" required>
                {% endif %}

                {% if form.phone_numbers.errors %}
                    <ul class="errorDetail">
                        {% for error in form.phone_numbers.errors %}
                            <li> {{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary-2 mt-1 mb-1" id="add-in"><span>Cliquez pour ajouter un autre numero <span class="ml-2">&plus;</span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End .form-group -->
        <script>
            var i = 1
            const MAX_LENGTH = 4
            function remove(el){
                document.getElementById('input-field').removeChild(el.parentNode.parentNode)
                i--
            }
            function add(){
                if(i<MAX_LENGTH){
                    div = document.createElement('div')
                    div.setAttribute('class', 'input-group mt-1')
                    html = ""
                    html += '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Un autre numero" name="{{form.phone_numbers.html_name}}">'
                    html += '<div class="input-group-append"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary-2" onclick="remove(this)"><span>&times</span></button></div>'
                    div.innerHTML = html
                    document.getElementById('input-field').appendChild(div)
                    i++
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('add-in').addEventListener('click', add)
        </script>
    </div><!-- .End .tab-pane -->
</form><!-- End .form-box -->
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code that you tried to your question, the model/form/view will help others answer

Comment: Can you please share your views.py , forms.py and request parameter code for better understandingg